# IntegrityError at /todo NOT NULL constraint failed: todo_todo.name i don't have a Foreign key only a name charfield

Tags: python, html, django

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ToDo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=" ")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import ToDo

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    # temp = ToDo.objects.all()
    # context = {'temp':temp}

    data = request.POST.get('name')
    print(data)
    context = {'data':data}

    return render(request, "todo/home.html", context)

def todo(request):
    # temp = ToDo.objects.all()
    # context = {'temp':temp}

    name = request.POST.get('name')

    todo = ToDo(name=name)
    todo.save()
    context = {'names' : todo}

    return render(request, "todo/todo.html", context)
```

**todo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>

    <form method="post" action="/todo">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <label for="name"> </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Add Task</button>
    </form>

    {% for x in names %}
    <h4>{{ x.name }}</h4>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried changing name's and id's everything that was there in youtube but no solution
I don't know where the error is occuring in the error page it shows `todo.save()` has the error but i don't know where the error is occuring at please help :(

Answer (score 1):

The error is described in the message "NOT NULL constraint failed: todo_todo.name". In your model you have added the field

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=" ")
```

This field does not allow null values.

To fix this you can either:

1. Allow for null values to be created

```py
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default=" ")
```

2. Add some check in your view, when name is null.

```py
    # Check if name is None or just whitespace
    if not name or name.isspace():
        # Handle this error: maybe redirect with an error message or render the form again
        context = {
            'error': 'Task name cannot be empty',
        }
        return render(request, "todo/todo.html", context)
```